Authenticate without Token is only allowed on Name Server - Photon Unity Networking Error
I am attempting to setup PlayFab + Photon authentication. It's been working for a while, but as of Photon Pun version 2.46 (I updated to a new version), it will show this error: Authenticate without Token is only allowed on Name Server and OpAuthenticate failed. Check log output and AuthValues. State: ConnectingToMasterServer. I don't know any way to fix this and I have been stuck on it for a while now.
I attempted re-writing the script from the documentation, re-installing Photon Pun, and re-making the Photon applications. None of these have worked.

In order to authenticate a user in Photon you must provide auth token which is retrieved via PlayFab client API. Example of how to retrieve the Photon auth token you need for Photon authentication:
string playFabId = "some ID";

// Use this API to get the token
// takes GetPhotonAuthenticationTokenRequest object which must include your PhotonApplicationId
// Returns GetPhotonAuthenticationTokenResult  which includes your token in GetPhotonAuthenticationTokenResult.PhotonCustomAuthenticationToken

PlayFabClientAPI.GetPhotonAuthenticationToken(new GetPhotonAuthenticationTokenRequest
    {
        // THIS OR YOUR APP ID DEPENDS ON WHAT YOU USE
        PhotonApplicationId = PhotonNetwork.PhotonServerSettings.AppSettings.AppIdRealtime,
    }, AuthenticatePhoton, OnPlayFabError);
            
// Use this to authenticate the user in Photon using the token you retrieved above (You can ofcourse separate it, in my example I just connected both.

private void AuthenticatePhoton(GetPhotonAuthenticationTokenResult tokenObj)
{
    var customAuth = new AuthenticationValues { AuthType = CustomAuthenticationType.Custom };
    customAuth.AddAuthParameter("username", playFabId);
    customAuth.AddAuthParameter("token", tokenObj.PhotonCustomAuthenticationToken);
    PhotonNetwork.AuthValues = customAuth;
            
    // ConnectUsingSettings() here or whatever is your next steps
}

Make sure you followed the dashboard setup steps here
